# resizing the width and height of easy slider version 1.7 with numeric nav

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

av been scratching my head because of this for too long.I would like to change the width and height of easy slider version 1.7,i have gone through the faqs part of this site  after researching in so many other places and cudn't get a solution.Please help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Pilot project</title>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){   
                $("#slider").easySlider({
                    auto: true, 
                continuous: true,
                numeric: true
            });
        }); 
    </script>
<link href="pilotp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen"/>
<link href="v1.7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://">Home</a></li>
        <span>
        <a href="http://">Web Hosting         </a>
        <a href="http://">Domain Registration </a>  
        </span>
</li>
<li><a href="http://">Consultancy</a>
        <span>
        <a href="http://">I.S Audit</a>
        <a href="http://">Information Security </a>
        </span>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://">Career's</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://">Contact Us</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://">Testimonials</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="slidercontainer" style="background-color:fuchsia;width:800px;height:300px"><!--Will hold the slider -->
    <div id="content" style="background-color:yellow;width:800px; height:299px;">
    <div id="slider" style="background-color:pink;width:800px;height:298px;">
       <ul>             
                <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/30"><img src="images/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/7"><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/25"><img src="images/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/26"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/27"><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the css

```
/* Easy Slider */
    #slider ul, #slider li,
    #slider2 ul, #slider2 li{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;

        }
    #slider2{margin-top:1em;}
    #slider ul li, #slider2 ul li{ 
        /* 
            define width and height of list item (slide)
            entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided here
        */ 
        width:800px;
        height:241px;
        overflow:hidden; 
        }   
    #prevBtn, #nextBtn,
    #slider1next, #slider1prev{ 
        display:block;
        width:30px;
        height:77px;
        position:absolute;
        left:-30px;
        top:71px;
        z-index:1000;
        }   
    #nextBtn, #slider1next{ 
        left:696px;
        }                                                       
    #prevBtn a, #nextBtn a,
    #slider1next a, #slider1prev a{  
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        width:30px;
        height:77px;
        background:url(../images/btn_prev.gif) no-repeat 0 0;   
        }   
    #nextBtn a, #slider1next a{ 
        background:url(../images/btn_next.gif) no-repeat 0 0;   
        }   

    /* numeric controls */

    ol#controls
        {   
        height:28px;
        margin-top:-20em;
        margin-bottom:1em;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-left:8px;
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;

        }
    ol#controls li
        {
        margin:0 15px 0 0; 
        padding:0;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        height:28px;
        line-height:28px;
        }
    ol#controls li a
        {
        float:left;
        height:28px;
        line-height:28px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        background:#DAF3F8;
        color:#555;
        padding:0 10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
    ol#controls li.current a
        {
        background:#5DC9E1;
        color:#fff;
        }
    ol#controls li a:focus, #prevBtn a:focus, #nextBtn a:focus{outline:none;}
    /*just added */
    ol#controls { margin: -30px 0 0 0 !important; } 

/* // Easy Slider */
```

Answer (score 0):

See line 73-76 in the CSS file screen.css:

```
        define width and height of list item (slide)
        entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided here
```

And also change the width of the container:

```
#container{ 
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    width:696px; /* change this */
    background:#fff;        
    margin-bottom:2em;
    }
```

Comment: i have played around with the figures in this part but all in vain ie the width and the height.

Comment: this is how i want it to be#slider ul li, #slider2 ul li{ 
  /* 
   define width and height of list item (slide)
   entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided here
  */ 
  width:800px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden; 
  }

Comment: try setting the same value for width on #container (a bit above in the css file)

Comment: i am a first timer and am having a hard time to get my code past the proper format test,for me to post it.just give me some few more minutes.

Comment: it shouldn't be so hard, see line 49 in the css file (you didn't post this bit), and change the value of width...

Comment: i will effect the changes afresh and will get back to you soon,thanx.

Comment: i did effect the changes and it didn't work,i think i wasn't very clear on the question,in my site i have a div called slider_container which is 800px long by 300px high,what i want is to make the whole of this div hold the sliding images which i will create.any help will be appreciated,i understand i will have to create images of the same length too,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it and it involved changing (increasing or decreasing) the width and height of

```
#slider ul li
{ 
    /* 
        define width and height of list item (slide)
        entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided   here
    */ 
    width:796px;
    height:246px;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

The width and height of the images are of importance also.
Thank you for you assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript file (easyslider.js) remove:

obj.width(w);
obj.height(h);